# Positioning of 3d boxes in JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-3d

I'm a beginner in JavaFx 3d modelling. I'm trying to create a 3d-model of boxes in a room. I have the dimensions of the boxes and the coords from the front-left-bottom corner of every box. I've tried to set the coords with setTranslateX(), but the result isn't correct. Here is the pice of my code where I try to set the coords:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Main.load.size(); i++) {
        Load l=Main.load.get(i);
        Box sphere = new Box(l.getLength()*10, l.getWidth()*10, l.getHeight()*10);
        sphere.setTranslateX(l.getX()*10);
        sphere.setTranslateY(l.getY()*10);
        sphere.setTranslateZ(l.getZ()*10);
        PhongMaterial m = new PhongMaterial();
        m.setDiffuseColor(new Color(Math.random(),Math.random(),Math.random(),1));
        m.setSpecularColor(Color.BLACK);
        sphere.setMaterial(m);
        root.getChildren().add(sphere);
    }
```

I hope someone can help me.

Here is an example:

Sizes:
blue (30,50,50)
pink (10,10,20)

Position:
blue (0,0,0)
pink (30,0,0)

[And this is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdiEx.png)

Comment: Could you please describe the effect you are seeing?
What version of Java are you using?
Have you set your 3D subscene's depthBuffer to true via the constructor?

Comment: @Birdasaur I updated the question with an example. I'm using Java 8. The depthBuffer is true. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It appears as though your objects are translated exactly where they should be assuming the camera you are using is a PerspectiveCamera.
PerspectiveCamera uses a 3D origin (0,0,0) in the center of the 3D scene.  Is that what you want or are your position values expecting one of the "corners" to be the origin?

Comment: @Birdasaur It's true, that I'm using a PerspecitveCamera. I want to insert the boxes in one and the same coordinate system. The pink box should be attached to the blue one. Sorry for my bad explanation.

Comment: When you do a translation of a JavaFX 3D object like a Box you need to account half the width of the object along any axis. The default placement for a Box is to be centered at the origin meaning the center of the Box object is at 0,0,0.  Your width is 30 * 10 but your translateX converts to 0*10=0.  So the right most edge of your blue box will be X=150 (300 / 2.0 =  150).  Your Pink Box has a translateX of 10*30=300.  The center of the pink box will be translated to 300 which means the left most edge will be at 300 - (width/2.0) = 300 - (50) = 250.

Comment: @Birdasaur Thank you! You have solved my problem!

Comment: Awesome! I reposted the last comment as an "answer" so you can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do a translation of a JavaFX 3D object like a Box you need to account half the width of the object along any axis. The default placement for a Box is to be centered at the origin meaning the center of the Box object is at 0,0,0. Your width is 30 * 10 but your translateX converts to 0*10=0. So the right most edge of your blue box will be X=150 (300 / 2.0 = 150). Your Pink Box has a translateX of 10*30=300. The center of the pink box will be translated to 300 which means the left most edge will be at 300 - (width/2.0) = 300 - (50) = 250.